# Qliksense script for transformation

Tags: qliksense

I want to transform my data in a QlikSense script where the data in every column is similar to "��345" I want to remove this �� data and transform the data into meaningful data in each column.

How can I transform all the columns at once from which I can remove the �� data from all the columns at once?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think first you'll have to find the character number that is hidden behind the `�` symbol(s). For this you can use [ord()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/Ord.htm) function.

`Ord` function will return the uniconde characted number from the given characted. For example: `Ord('A')` will return `65`. `Ord('B')` will return `66` etc.

You can get the first character from your field and determine its number. Something like:

Select single value from your field. Create a simple text box and use similar measure:

```
Ord( left(MyField, 1) )
```

Once the character number is identified then you can go back to the script.

Lets imagine that we want to replace all instances of `A` with an empty string:

```
// create variable that will hold the replace function
// the $1 is representing the first parameter passed to the function
set vClear = replace($1, chr(65), '');

RawData:
Load    
    Temp, // keep Temp just as a reference
    // Call the variable/function vClear
    // on each row that is being loaded
    $(vClear(Temp)) as ClearedTemp,
;
Load
    'ABCDXYZ' as Temp
AutoGenerate 1
;
```

Once the app is reloaded the value for `ClearedTemp` will be `BCDXYZ` (`A` is replaced with and empty string)

This approach can be applied to as many fields are you want/need.

P.S. there might be multiple different characters that are hidden behind `�`. You'll have to find out if there are more than one or its always the same character. If there are more that one characted then you'll have to extend the `vClear` definition and call `replace` multiple times.

P.S.1 If there are too many fields, where the function should be applied, then potentially we can use some automation to create the required script. But this will complicate the current example and thats why i havent included this approach in this answer

Answer (score 1):

I think Stefan's got the right answer here, especially since that method lets you control the script directly and choose which fields you want to update. However, if you have a lot of fields you want to update at once and you're not worried too much with formatting, like with dates, you can do something like this:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense load script]

The idea here is to dynamically write the load script that removes those `�` values. Specifically, we create an empty string variable called `vNewLoad`, then loop through all of the fields in the our original `data` table using `For vFieldNo = 1 to NoOfFields('data')`. This will give us the field index for each field in that table, which we then use to get the actual field name using `Let vCurrentField = FieldName(vFieldNo, 'data');`. Then we update our new load variable to include a `Replace()` function for that field, where we replace the `�` value with an empty string `''`, effectively removing it from the field values. Next we clean up our new load variable to get rid of the first extra comma by using `Let vNewLoad = Mid('$(vNewLoad)', 2);`. Finally, we load a new table, `[new data]`, that utilizes our dynamically-created load script by just using `Load $(vNewLoad) Resident [data];`.

And that should get the job done:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table result]

Comment: Thank you, SmoothBrane and Stefan Stoichev. Now the code is working.